# Regex that does not contain specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please help me to write a regex for email validation. It should be a generic email validation but the email address should not contain exact yahoo or gmail or rediff word between @ and . (dot). Eg

```
something@gmail.com = false
something@gmail1.com = true
something@abcgmail.com = true
something@yahoo.com = false
```

Apart from these, it should have all generic validations. I tried this one but no luck:

```
/^[A-z0-9]+[A-z0-9_\.]*@((?!(gmail|yahoo|rediff|hotmail|live|@)).)*\.[A-z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: `Tried few, but no luck.` post that..

Comment: /^[A-z0-9]+[A-z0-9_\.]*@((?!(gmail|yahoo|rediff|hotmail|live|@)).)*\.[A-z0-9]+$/

Answer (score 0):

> should not contain exact yahoo or gmail or rediff word between @ and . (dot).

Change from the `@` to dot part in your regex like below.

```
@(?!yahoo\.|gmail\.|rediff\.)\w+\.
```

ie,

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9_\.]*@(?!yahoo\.|gmail\.|rediff\.|hotmail\.|live\.)\w+\.[A-z0-9]+$/i
```

or

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9_\.]*@(?!(?:yahoo|gmail|rediff|hotmail|live)\.)\w+\.[A-Z0-9]+$/i
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wM0/4)